# The right-handed (RH) thread vs the left-handed (LH) thread in screws

Tags: screws

I know that there are screws with these features and know how to distinguish them. Usually there are screws on the right thread.

When and what type of screws should I use?

Comment: Generally speaking, every screw you will encounter or should use in a "household" context will be RH threaded. I've only used LH screws in automotive/bicycle/industrial machinery type situations.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the application for which you would consider a LH thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Differences:

- Righty Tighty, Lefty loosey doesn't work with left-handed screws.
- Right-handed screws move away from you if you rotate them in a clockwise direction, whereas left-handed screws move towards you.

## When to Use Left-Handed Screws

When [fretting induced precession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession_(mechanical)) would cause the right-handed nut/screw to loosen, a left handed nut/screw should be used.

Comment: Chew tawkin 'bout rotational loosing, bub?

Comment: Chrysler products used LH lug nuts for years, but only on the left side of the vehicle

Comment: I read of a large transit system (NYC?) that had LHT sockets and light-bulbs to deter bulb theft.  They were a huge customer, and it only needed a production line change in the pressed metal in the socket and bulb base.

Comment: I've found that sometimes the right hand (on the wrench) doesn't know what the left hand (thread) is doing.

Comment: @HerrBag - It was all fun and games sitting back snickering with my buddy at one of our less informed friends trying to remove a flat until he put a swede on it and managed to twist the stud off. Dodge'm

Answer (score 1):

Most common use is probably on a turn buckle.  Think screen door sagging fix.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can easily distinguish right hand and left hand thread by visualize it.and it is depend on your need that what type of screw you can use for which purpose.